# How can I use as.formula and paste to form equations

Tags: r, formula

I have a group of variables, for example, `vars <- c("age", "gender", "city")`. I need to fit a model: `fit <- coxme(Surv(tt, st) ~ age + gender + city + (1|id), data = df)`. Everything works well. But as I have many variables, I need to use as.formula:

```
vars <- c("age", "gender", "city")
fit <- coxme::coxme(as.formula(paste("Surv(tt, st) ~", 
                        paste(vars, collapse = " + "), 
                        "+ (1|id), data = df")))
```

I got the following error info:

> `Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : <text>:1:121: unexpected ','`

How could I write this equation?

Comment: In the fit model, why the format is "coxme::coxme", rather than "coxme"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include `", data = df"`.  The formula is just the first part.  Try something like this:

```
vars <- c("age", "gender", "city")
fit  <- coxme(as.formula(paste("Surv(tt, st) ~", 
                               paste(vars, collapse=" + "), 
                               "+ (1|id)")),
              data=df)
```

Comment: It works, problem solved, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, @Bob.

Comment: In the fit model, the format of "coxme::coxme" is necessary? why? 
The format of "coxme" works.

Comment: @Bob, I didn't add that. It looks like MrFlick did that to identify the package that houses the function you're calling.